# Use AWK add new line if match exists

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with the following format:

```
aaa@ bbb
bbb@ ccc& ddddd@ aaaf
ccc@ ddd& eee: abcd& dassda
```

The output should be:

```
aaaa@ bbb
bbb@ ccc&
ddddd@ aaaf
ccc@ ddd&
eee@ abcd& dassda
```

How would I be able to achieve this using AWK? I've tried sed and awk but I can only print a new line after the delimeter, I don't know how to print the whole thing on the next line.

Answer (score 8):

sed :

```
sed 's/& /\&\n/' file
```

in case you need replace all `&` on the each string just add `g` after last `/`.

awk :

```
awk '{ sub(/& /,"&\n"); print }'
```

in case you need replace all `&` on the each string use `gsub` instead `sub`.

Comment: can you explain how awk way works?