# inserting gaps in a text file using shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How can I insert gaps at certain places in a text file using shell script? For example, I want to insert enter after word "complete" wherever it is found in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is using `sed` :

```
sed 's/complete/complete\n/g' filename
```

To replace the content of the file directly, use `sed -i...`.
To backup the original file with a `.bak` extension, use `sed -i.bak...`.
In order to provide a more precise answer, your question should be more accurate.

Comment: This, just like [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210477) and [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35298), will only work with `gnu sed`.